# what can we do instead of ajax call in javascript, if we want data in php in the same file?

Tags: javascript, php

Is there any Alternative to ajax hit??

If the condition is you need to get the javascript variable in php, but without using ajax call.

Comment: Your point is not clear. show some code

Comment: You can make a redirect to an other site with the variable as get parameter for php.

Comment: I don't want to use redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You need send the variable in the request, there is not other way.

If the variable is almost always needed you can set the variable like cookies and check it in PHP or in the same request you make in the header (in the case an authentication) or in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to json_encode the data in php and print it inside a script tag and assigning it to a variable.

For example

```php
<script>
    var phpData = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I want to use a javascript variable in php, not a php variable in javascript.

Comment: My mistake. Its OK using jQuery. Also you can post what you want using ajax request such as $.post, the jQuery documentation is very usefull to read. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution for this-

I used jquery and placed that value in a hidden field and at the action of form I got the values by request.

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
       var js_data='abcd';
       var name = "example-data";

       var element = document.getElementById(name);
       if (!element) {
            element = document.createElement("input");
            element.type = "hidden";
            element.name = element.id = name;
            jQuery('.some_class_of_your_form').append(element);    
       }
       element.setAttribute("value", js_data);
     });
```

and then simply, 
You can get the data in php by using either $_GET['example-data'] or $_POST['example-data'] according to your form's action.